# How to slide image with finger touch in android?

Tags: java, android, touch

I am developing an android application in which I want to slide images with finger touch. I have implemented an `onClickListener` with which I can slide images but I don't know how to implement finger touch functionality.

Please suggest me any method how to slide images with finger touch. Any Suggestion or any tutorial or method will be helpful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use onTouchListner method instead of onClickListner. Below onTouchListners example is given..

```
public class abc extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{
     ImageView img;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one);

                img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                img.setOnTouchListener(this);
     }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {       
                  // Here u can write code which is executed after the user touch on the screen 
                     break; 
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {             
                   // Here u can write code which is executed after the user release the touch on the screen    
                 break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {  
               // Here u can write code which is executed when user move the finger on the screen   
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thanx  for help mohit should i write action similar to that i write in onclick listener,or some other way

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is an `ViewFlipper`. This will help you to get the look what you are expecting.

[This mgiht be helpful](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Samples/localservice/com/sample/slide/SlideOnTouch.java.htm)

[check this too](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-viewflipper-and-slidingdrawer.html)

Or try this,

In your xml just add only this,

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
</ViewFlipper>
```

need not enclose with any ImageViews.

Now do this in your coding.

Considering that you have stored your Images in a array like this,

```
int gallery_grid_Images[]={R.drawable.gallery_image_1,R.drawable.gallery_image_2,R.drawable.gallery_image_3,
        R.drawable.gallery_image_4,R.drawable.gallery_image_5,R.drawable.gallery_image_6,R.drawable.gallery_image_7,
        R.drawable.gallery_image_8,R.drawable.gallery_image_9,R.drawable.gallery_image_10
        };
```

Now in your onCreate(),

```
viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
 for(int i=0;i<gallery_grid_Images.length;i++)
        {
        //  This will create dynamic image view and add them to ViewFlipper
            setFlipperImage(gallery_grid_Images[i]);
        }
```

And now add this method to your activity,

```
private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
    Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res+"");
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
    viewFlipper.addView(image);
}
```

That's it. And now using your `viewFlipper.showNext();`  and  `viewFlipper.showPrevious();`
methods you can show your dynamic images.

Answer (score 2):

I would really suggest you using RealViewSwitcher class by Marc Reichelt, get it [from here](http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html) It provides a slight view swticher, like android launcher does.

Answer (score 2):

Views can catch touch events -- take a look at [OnTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) which lets you catch [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)s like touch down and touch up.  You could use a handler to loop, moving the image/view to the currently touched place after a touch down event until a touch up event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Gallery widget

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) the link to the API

There is also a [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html). For me it was very helpful :)

Comment: This class was deprecated in API level 16.